# finite and infinite product of discrete space

Tags: general-topology

It is known that finite product of any discrete space is discrete. But infinite product of discrete space need not to be discrete. The main reason is that the any singletion in  infinite product space is never be open ? or is there any infinite  product of discrete spaces that each singletion is open subset in it?

Comment: I wonder that in generally  we  can say each singletion never be open in  infinite product space or not?

Comment: You are on the right track: what would be required to get an open neighborhood in the product topology consisting of a single point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that the definition of the product $X$ of a family of spaces $X_\lambda$ indexed by $\lambda\in\Lambda$ has as a basis for its topology the collection of open sets of the form $$\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}U_\lambda$$ such that $U_\lambda\subset X_\lambda$ and $U_\lambda\neq X_\lambda$ for only finitely many $\lambda$. That is, every open set can be written as a union of such 'open rectangles'. From this definition, can you prove that if there exists an open $U\in X$ which consists of a single point, then $X_\lambda$ must be a single point for all but finitely many $\lambda$?

---

I should add that there is a slightly slicker answer for products of finite spaces which relies on Tychanoff's theorem. If $X=\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}X_\lambda$ and $X_\lambda$ is finite (with two or more points each) and discrete for all $\lambda$, then $X$ is compact by Tychanoff's theorem. What do we know about compact discrete spaces in terms of their cardinality?